# Spring Boot 1.4.1 exception trying to use SSL cipher TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, spring-boot, tomcat8

I have a Spring Boot 1.4.1 application using a Tomcat 8.5.5 embedded container. I would like to configure it to use a specific SSL cipher, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384. Here is the relevant section of application.yml:

```
  server:
    port: 9052
    ssl:
      enabled: true
      ciphers: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
      protocol: TLS
      key-store: /myApp/Keystore_Trial.jks
      key-store-type: JKS
      key-store-password: changeit
      key-password: changeit
      key-alias: MyAppTrial
      client-auth: want
```

Using this configuration, the app fails to start with this exception:

```
[ERROR] 2017-09-07 14:21:15,358 org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol - Failed to start end point associated with ProtocolHandler [https-jsse-nio-9052]
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: sslUtilBase.noneSupported
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.getEnabled(SSLUtilBase.java:87)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.<init>(SSLUtilBase.java:61)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSEUtil.<init>(JSSEUtil.java:151)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSEImplementation.getSSLUtil(JSSEImplementation.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:91)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.initialiseSsl(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:81)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:244)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:874)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:590)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:969)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:225)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.addPreviouslyRemovedConnectors(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:233)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.start(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:178)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.startEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:297)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:145)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:544)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1186)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175)
    at com.bnsf.hubplanner.Application.main(Application.java:29)
[ERROR] 2017-09-07 14:21:15,360 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService - Failed to start connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-9052]]
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-9052]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:225)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.addPreviouslyRemovedConnectors(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:233)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.start(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:178)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.startEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:297)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:145)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:544)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1186)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175)
    at com.bnsf.hubplanner.Application.main(Application.java:29)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: service.getName(): "Tomcat";  Protocol handler start failed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:976)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 13 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: sslUtilBase.noneSupported
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.getEnabled(SSLUtilBase.java:87)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.<init>(SSLUtilBase.java:61)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSEUtil.<init>(JSSEUtil.java:151)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSEImplementation.getSSLUtil(JSSEImplementation.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:91)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.initialiseSsl(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:81)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:244)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:874)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:590)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:969)
    ... 14 common frames omitted
[INFO ] 2017-09-07 14:21:15,381 org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol - Pausing ProtocolHandler ["https-jsse-nio-9052"]
[INFO ] 2017-09-07 14:21:15,381 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService - Stopping service Tomcat
```

The relevant lines of [SSLUtilBase](https://www.javatips.net/api/Tomcat-master/tomcat-trunk/java/org/apache/tomcat/util/net/SSLUtilBase.java) show that the error means it is not finding that cipher in the list of supported ciphers, but I've seen examples of people [using similar cipher configuration](http://devopsunixandjava.com/spring-boot-embedded-jettytomcat-ssltls/) with success and the [Tomcat documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/api/index.html) seems to show that it is supported.

Comment: See [Bug 60138 - protocol TLSV1.2 causes exception text sslUtilBase.noneSupported](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60138): ***Verified fix in 8.5.6***

Comment: Awesome, thank you. I spent hours searching but did not find that. I will post the final solution next week.